# How to setup web-hook using custom commit message?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to set up a web-hook using custom commit message. I want to trigger web hook when developer commit files with 'Proceed with Migration' Commit message.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to run a jenkins job if this is present in the git commit message?

Comment: Yes. you are correct.

Comment: YEARS ago I wrote this, does what you want it to but will require some refitting for your purposes https://github.com/sanguis/drupal-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts

Comment: Thanks and it really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me, simply check the latest git commit message and selectively build your job:

```
def resultlog = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log  -1 --pretty=%B')
    if (resultlog.contains("Proceed with Migration")) {
    //your code
    }
```